# Can't connect to gtalk with python and xmpppy

Tags: python, xmpp, google-talk

When try connect to gtalk I get this error:

> An error occurred while looking up _xmpp-client._tcp.talk.google.com

The code is here:
https://gist.github.com/1396074

Comment: -1 this question is useless without the code (the gist has been deleted)

Answer (score 1):

Do not pass the (incorrect) server name into `cl.connect()` on line 11.  The SRV lookup will go to `_xmpp-client._tcp.gmail.com` then (taken from the JID), which should work.  Passing in a server is only used for incorrectly configured XMPP servers.