# how to send message to gtalk using python?

Tags: python, xmpp, ejabberd, google-talk

i'm trying  to work with XMPP Servers and it's related python libraries and i'm gonna send a message to a google user with my account using the below python code segment :

```
import sys,os,xmpp
jid=xmpp.protocol.JID('MYGOOGLEACCOUNT@gmail.com')
cl=xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(), debug=[])
cl.connect()
cl.auth(jid.getNode(),'MYPASSWORD')
cl.sendInitPresence()
cl.send(xmpp.protocol.Message('MYTARGET','MYMESSAGE'))
```

but i got this error :

> An error occurred while looking up _xmpp-client._tcp.gmail.com

ok now i wondered how can i solve this problem . after that how can i receive that message using python instead of gtalk.
tnx

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look here for a finished gtalk client: http://wiki.woodpecker.org.cn/moin/GoogleTalkBot
also I find another similar question too, you can review here:
[Can't connect to gtalk with python and xmpppy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280727/cant-connect-to-gtalk-with-python-and-xmpppy)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've got [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/) or [PyDNS](http://pydns.sourceforge.net/) installed.